# Unity Face Object With Off-center Pivot Point?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, position, transform, quaternions

I'm trying to create a "billboard" effect where a quad/gameObject always faces a target object (the camera) around the Y axis.  This is working fine as per the code below, but I want to add an optional offset to the pivot point on the X axis.
So rather than rotating around the center point (default behaviour), I want the quad to rotate around a new point thats *n* units off of the center point, while still facing the target object.

This will run in Update().

**Currently Working Code Without Offset**

```
transform.LookAt(camera.transform, Vector3.up);
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0); // Only affects Y Axis.
```

The offset I need is calculated by the function below.  It is tested to be correct by moving a child GameObject by this value.

Both the leftObj and rightObj are children of the GameObject I want to be rotating.

```
    public float GetCenterPos()
    {
        Vector3 left = leftObj.transform.localPosition;
        Vector3 right = rightObj.transform.localPosition;

        Vector3 center = (left + right) / 2f;
        return center.x;
    }
```

**Top Down View of My Problem**
[image]

I have tried combinations of RotateAround, but I can't figure out how to get it to face the correct object and what the pivot should be relative to the offset.
I have also googled around, and I can't find a solution to this problem that I feel is relatively simple.

To recap:  I don't need a rotational offset, and *I don't want to add an extra parent to change the pivot* like many other answers suggest.  The offset gets calculated dynamically in Update.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Simplest way for something like this is to wrap your object in an additional parent. Billboard the parent object instead and make the children have the desired local offset -> done ;)

Comment: @derHugo  I appreciate the reply, but like I said at the end of the post, I am not interested in doing so, despite it being suggested by basically everyone everywhere lol.
Because I have other functionality that requires the gameObject to be the first parent, it's not ideal.  I appreciate the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been tinkering with it for a while, and I came up with this solution.  It's not ideal because it requires storing a reference to the starting position, which breaks some of the other movement functionality I need, but it does answer my original question.

Before beginning the code above (either in start or before a bool flag is set, whatever) store a reference to the object's localPosition (`startPos`)

Then before calling `LookAt`, adjust the position to take into account the offset.

```
transform.localPosition = new Vector3(startPos.x + offset, transform.localPosition.y, transform.localPosition.z);
transform.LookAt(camController.transform, Vector3.up);
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
```

To clarify, the reason why I need a reference to `startPos` is because otherwise I would be adding the offset every frame, resulting in the object just moving constantly, rather than using a consistent value.

I just set the startPos before and after toggling the "billboard" functionality to keep it updated.  Not ideal, but it does work.